# NodeJS/Express/Angular: $http.get returning Status 300: Multiple Choices (with no body data)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, http-status-codes

I'm 100% stumped on this one and don't even know where to begin looking, so if I need to add any detail anywhere please let me know.

I'll start with the main thing: I **cannot** reproduce this on my localhost; it is only happening on my live server (a VPS running Linux and serving over HTTPS).

I have ExpressJS set up with this route:

```
 app.get('/api/checkScraper2/:id', api.checkScraper2);
```

Which serves this:

```
exports.checkScraper2 = function(req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log("Checking for " + id)
    // More stuff, but nothing is being logged at all + response is already 300 before we get here
}
```

In AngularJS, my `$http.get` call is:

```
function nextScrape() {
    $http.get('/api/checkScraper2/' + userId).then(function(obj) {

        var msg = JSON.parse(obj.data);

        console.log("Got some data !")
        console.log(msg);

    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err)
        $location.path('/setup');
    });
```

This is redirecting me to `/setup` straight away, and I can't see a call to `/api/checkScraper2/abc12345` (`:id` is a string) in my Express server log. The `err` dumped contains no data, just "300: Multiple Choices"

It seems as though the root cause is Angular's `$http` module, as my server isn't giving out any `300` error nor is anything appearing in my back-end logs.

I can do a little hack with `$timeout` to make the function work:

```
var triedNext = 0; // This bit is a debugging attempt just in case the first 
function nextScrape() {
    $http.get('/api/checkScraper2/' + userId).then(function(obj) {
        var msg = JSON.parse(obj.data);
        console.log("Got some data !")
        console.log(msg);
    }, function(err) {
        console.log(err)
        triedNext++

        if(triedNext === 5){
            $location.path('/setup');
        }else{
            $timeout(nextScrape, 1500); // hack to wait 1.5s then try again
        }
    });
```

This works. Any idea on what might be causing this?

Comment: Did you check for a registering the same route twice?

Comment: @RomanDibikhin Yep, in fact that's why it's `/api/checkScraper2/:id` and not just `checkScraper` - a last-ditch effort at seeing whether I'd missed a duplicate route!

Comment: Check your browser's request for $http.get path in network tab.

Comment: What is a value of `userId`?

Comment: @RomanDibikhin I can see the request, it's trying to make it to `https://host.com/api/checkScraper/561b49d57f22d44d522a8995` (just a MongoDB `_id`)

Comment: There is `checkScraper2` in your code and `checkScraper` in your request. Is it ok?

Comment: @RomanDibikhin Sorry that's an error on my part. The request in the browser is for `checkScraper2`.

Comment: How is your app hosted locally and at VPS?